# Static Initializers vs Instance Initializers vs Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, static, initializer

I am studying for an exam about Java. While I was studying, I have encountered syntaxes in java which are unfamiliar to me. Such as a curly braces({}) unside a class body without a name, some has a static keyword. I have found out that they are called "Initializers". Can anyone help me point out key differences among them and how they differ from a Constructor. Thanks

Comment: I recommend you this book http://www.apress.com/9781430247647 chapters 3 and 4

Comment: @Reieus he also asked about Anonymous code blocks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The main difference between them is the order they are executed. To illustrate, I will explain them with an example:

```
public class SomeTest {

    static int staticVariable;
    int instanceVariable;        

    // Static initialization block:
    static {
        System.out.println("Static initialization.");
        staticVariable = 5;
    }

    // Instance initialization block:
    {
        System.out.println("Instance initialization.");
        instanceVariable = 10;
    }

    // Constructor
    public SomeTest() {
        System.out.println("Constructor executed.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeTest();
        new SomeTest();
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Static initalization.
Instance initialization.
Constructor executed.
Instance initialization.
Constructor executed.
```

Briefly talking:

- Static initialization blocks run once the class is loaded by the JVM.
- Instance initialization blocks run before the constructor each time you instantiate an object.
- Constructor (obviously) run each time you instantiate an object.

Comment: This is a good answer.  But I'd like to add that constructors are much more common than instance initializers.  I think the main use-case for instance initializers are for doing initialization in anonymous inner classes, which can't have constructors because they lack names.

Comment: very simple and nice example +1

Answer (score 1):

A Constructor is called once when a new instance of a class is created. The values initialized in the constructor belong to the scope of the instance. Each Instance may have a different value for the same field initialized in the Constructor.

Static Initializers are useful for executing setup code in Static Classes and filling out data structures in Enums. They are called once, in order from top to bottom when the Class is loaded into the JVM and the data exists within the scope of the Class or Enum. All references to the Class will return the same value for fields initialized in the Static Initializers

Unnamed Curly Braces are Anonymous code blocks that scope reference names. If you create a reference inside the blocks, you can not get the value of that reference outside the block. If you find yourself needing them it's a sign you need to refactor your code into more methods.

Comment: "Unnamed Curly Braces" are called [instance initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6)

Answer (score -2):

This is the kind of thing you really need to look in your textbook to get an answer. However I can give you some pointers. Its been some years since I programmed Java, so any information I gave you is general.

Generally a nameless block with curly braces is  an anonymous function. Static initializers initialize data that is global to all instances of that class, and runs once the first time the class is referenced.  You need to be careful about how you use static properties or methods.  With this information you can find accurate details in your text books.